# react-router and cordova not working

Tags: cordova, react-router, file-uri

React-router can't seem to handle anything run over a local file protocol.

It interprets the third slash after file:// as a route.

So if you create an app and try to run it from file:///C:/myapp.html

It thinks you are attempting to access the route /C:/myapp.html and throws an error saying

"Warning: Location "/C:/myapp.html" does not match any routes.

Is there a way to make react-router work when an app is served over the file protocol?

As of right now the router doesn't work at all with cordova/phonegap because they serve everything as a local file.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that the BrowserHistory cannot be used with the file protocole.

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2639

The HashHistory seems to work, I guess you could give it a try?

```
// import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
import createHashHistory from 'history/lib/createHashHistory';

// let history = createBrowserHistory();
let history = createHashHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path='/' component={YourComponent} />
  </Router>,
  document.querySelector('#your-app-wrapper')
);
```

Comment: Hashhistory works beautifully - incorporated into my build script

Comment: Thanks, mate. A great help